# vscode extension API editor.replace replace only first match while match 2 instances

Tags: vscode-extensions, vscode-api

developing an VS code extension where

- search for color hex code in whole css document
- replace the color hex code with variable name

although it match all color hex code but replace the only first instance and stops

below is the code snippet

```js
export function activate(context: vscode.ExtensionContext) {
    let activeEditor = vscode.window.activeTextEditor;
    function replaceWithinDocument() {
        if (!activeEditor) {
            return;
        }
        const text = activeEditor.document.getText();

        const reg = new RegExp('(?<color>#[0-9a-f]{3,6})', 'gim');

        const matches = text.matchAll(reg);

        const variableList = {};
        let i = 0;

        for (const match of matches) {
            const { index, groups } = match;
            i++;
            console.log({ match });
            const startPos = activeEditor.document.positionAt(index!);
            const endPos = activeEditor.document.positionAt(index! + match[0].length);
            console.log({ i, startPos, endPos });
            //Creating a new range with startLine, startCharacter & endLine, endCharacter.
            let range = new vscode.Range(startPos, endPos);
            // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/naming-convention
            Object.assign(variableList, { [`--var-${i}`]: groups?.color });
            activeEditor.edit(editBuilder => {
                editBuilder.replace(range, `--var-${i}`);
            });
        }

        console.log({ variableList });
    }

   function triggerUpdateDecorations(throttle = false) {
        if (timeout) {
            clearTimeout(timeout);
            timeout = undefined;
        }
        if (throttle) {
            timeout = setTimeout(replaceWithinDocument, 500);
        } else {
            replaceWithinDocument();
        }
    }

    if (activeEditor) {
        triggerUpdateDecorations();
    }
```

[image: Debug console for extension]

final document

```css
body {
  background-color: --var-1;
  color: #223344;
}
```

you can see in the screenshot that `console.log({ variableList });` have both color code in it

so what is wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [allow delay between edits via vscode extension api](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/87871#issuecomment-569651262).  Because of the particular nature of the `editBuilder` object

> The editBuilder "expires" once you return from the callback passed to
> TextEditor.edit.

you should put your `matches` loop inside the call to the `edit` call like this sample code:

```js
  //  get your matches above first

  editor.edit(editBuilder => {

    let i = 0;

    for (const match of matches) {

      // build your replacement here

      const matchStartPos = document.positionAt(match.index);
      const matchEndPos = document.positionAt(match.index + match[0].length);
      const matchRange = new Range(matchStartPos, matchEndPos);
      editBuilder.replace(matchRange, resolvedReplace);

    }
  }).then(async (resolved) => {

  });
```

Comment: this works like charm, although I have tried `asyn editor.edit( (eb) => {
await eb.replace(); }`
that also worked but in that case replaing rtext on wrong index. Thanks